# Ajax Call Duplicates HTML Output

Tags: primefaces

I came across this by accident today, and it's left me confused.

I've got this contrived example of jsf/primefaces code

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<f:view
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head />
    <h:body>
    <h:form id="testform">
        <p:panelGrid id="testDisplay"  >
            <p:panelGrid  >
               <p:commandButton value="tester">
                        <p:ajax update="testDisplay"  />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton id="reload" value="reload" action="test" ajax="false" />
    </h:form>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

it renders 2 buttons on the page, a button marked 'tester' and 'reload'

The tester button wraps a p:ajax tag. That tag updates the outer-most p:panelGrid

like this (I can't post an image, I have a poor reputation)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIx0a.jpg

click the Tester button and the panelGrid doubles up, keep going and get more.

Does anyone know why? I've tried searching for it and I have to admit that I don't even know how to properly describe the problem to search for it!

So what's up?
There's a couple of workarounds: change the outer panelGrid to an h:panelGrid, or set the id on the inner panelGrid.

Comment: Sure you don't have `autoUpdate` on the panelgrid? And what is your PF version?

Comment: I'm using 5.2. I haven't explicitly set autoupdate on the panelGrid. It doesn't seem to be an attribute I can set according to [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/5.2/core/). Where can i set/unset it?  Then I'll give it a try.

edit - I added autoUpdate="false" to each tag one at a time and the result was the same

Comment: Your page doesn't render a `<DOCTYPE` or a `<html`. I don't know what the browser thinks to do for such a page.

Comment: @ Holger ---you're right I don't have that in example. The page sits in a liferay portal. The portal wraps the out put in the following `<!DOCTYPE html> <html class="aui ltr" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> `